# Use case of explicit deletion of move constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move

I understand move constructor, but in some places I see move constructor is deleted. In what scenarios is deleting a move constructor is useful/makes sense?

Even if the the object needs to be singleton, we can delete the copy constructor but not the move constructor.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last part. If you delete the copy constructor, the move construction is also automatically disabled unless you explicitly re-enable it. If you do enable move construction for a singleton... Wowie-zowie that would be bad. The singleton could be gutted by the move and leave it in a safe-to-destroy but otherwise unusable state.

Comment: I do not understand.  Why can you not delete the move constructor?  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: If you allow move construction, it means you can have more than one instance of your Singleton, even though only one of those instances is usable. The Singleton pattern implies that there is a single widely reachable instance, and allowing it to move could make that instance unusable. If you allow move assignment, it implies there is more than one instance between which to move a value, which is also contrary to the Singleton pattern.

Comment: If a type is implicitly not copyable because it has a non copyable member, then you could get away with just deleting move construction and assignment to prevent any copy or assignment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the reply. I was thinking that a move constructor can be invoked by std::move() on the argument and I was assuming that the call to std::move will destroy the source(call the destructor of the argument being passed). Now I learnt that std::move is just static_cast to R-value reference type. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its generally not needed, other than for purposes of being verbose. Just an example of "can doesnt mean should". In your example of deleting the copy constructor (or even just defined), the move constructor is *implicitly* deleted. In scenarios where this is done, you could imagine explicitly deleting the move constructor as well.